# How to add a value in a list inside another list?

Tags: java, list

I have a list of lists, using the following code:

```
ArrayList<List<String>> keyHold = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
String cold[] = new String[]{"actions","cold","enabled"};
List<String> lCold = Arrays.asList(cold);
lCold.add(Rows.getRow(rowNum, 0));              
keyHold.add(lCold);         

String warm[] = new String[]{"actions","warm","enabled"};
List<String> lWarm = Arrays.asList(warm);
lWarm.add(Rows.getRow(rowNum, 1));  
keyHold.add(lWarm);
```

This goes on for many more variations of this, with the strings changing.

What I want to do is iterate through my list of lists, and for each list within, add a value to that list. So far, I am struggling for an answer and any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: use List<List<String>> keyHold = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); instead of ArrayList<List<String>> keyHold = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this code will help you reach your goal, seems to me that because you are calling .add() on a List which is an interface and not an implementation of the List interface (Like ArrayList/LinkedList are) you are getting the error.

```
    String cold[] = new String[]{"actions","cold","enabled"};
    String warm[] = new String[]{"actions","warm","enabled"};

    List<String> lCold = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(cold));
    List<String> lWarm = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(warm));

    List<ArrayList> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();//Create a list of lists
    listOfLists.add((ArrayList<String>) lCold);
    listOfLists.add((ArrayList<String>) lWarm);

    Iterator<ArrayList> firstIterator = listOfLists.iterator();
    while(firstIterator.hasNext()){//Iterate list of lists
        ArrayList<String> list = firstIterator.next();
        list.add("String");
    }       

    for(String s: lCold){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    for(String s: lWarm){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I just came back to this problem and remembered posting about it, this is great thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To iterate through your list of lists, you will use an iterator that returns `List<String>`. Then, you can work on the current `List<String>` instance stored in the `List<List<String>>` and add an element or do other stuff.

Here's an example:

```
for (List<String> stringList : keyHold) {
    if (<condition>) {
        stringList.add(<value you want/need to add>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The static method[`asList(T... a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)from the `Arrays class`returns only a **list-view** of the array. That's why you are getting an exception (`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`), when you try to add an element to the list.